# Delay in prelogin response when connecting to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, linked-server

I have set up a linked server to an Azure SQL 2014 managed instance. The vendor gave me a SQL login and password to use. I can open a direct connection in SSMS and run queries. But when I try to run queries through the linked server, I get this error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ABC" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ABC" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response".
Msg 258, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].
```

The vendor says they are not seeing any issues on their end. Anybody have any ideas where to start troubleshooting this? Thanks.

Comment: If you right click the linked server object in SSMS, and click "Test Connection", does it succeed or it also provides an error? When querying the linked server, do you get the error you mentioned immediately or after a fixed amount of time, and if it's a fixed amount of time, how long is it?

Comment: Same error whether I run a query or test the connection. Same error if I use OPENQUERY. Takes about 3 to 5 seconds to return the error message.